# Getting user defined possible solutions from a matrix, matlab

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, indexing, combinations

I have a matrix

```
My_big_matrix_=rand(21,4)
   My_big_matrix_=[ 
   1.0000    0.8147    0.0357    0.7655
    2.0000    0.9058    0.8491    0.7952
    3.0000    0.1270    0.9340    0.1869
    4.0000    0.9134    0.6787    0.4898
    5.0000    0.6324    0.7577    0.4456
    6.0000    0.0975    0.7431    0.6463
    7.0000    0.2785    0.3922    0.7094
    8.0000    0.5469    0.6555    0.7547
    9.0000    0.9575    0.1712    0.2760
   10.0000    0.9649    0.7060    0.6797
   11.0000    0.1576    0.0318    0.6551
   12.0000    0.9706    0.2769    0.1626
   13.0000    0.9572    0.0462    0.1190
   14.0000    0.4854    0.0971    0.4984
   15.0000    0.8003    0.8235    0.9597
   16.0000    0.1419    0.6948    0.3404
   17.0000    0.4218    0.3171    0.5853
   18.0000    0.9157    0.9502    0.2238
   19.0000    0.7922    0.0344    0.7513
   20.0000    0.9595    0.4387    0.2551
   21.0000    0.6557    0.3816    0.5060];
```

I want to get different combinations of rows  to get matrices  of size (7*4)

these combinations should be

```
Combination_(1,1)={1,4,7,10,13,16,19}
Combination_(1,2)={1,5,7,10,13,16,19}
Combination_(1,3)={1,6,7,10,13,16,19}
Combination_(1,4)={2,4,7,10,13,16,19}
Combination_(1,5)={2,5,7,10,13,16,19}
Combination_(1,6)={2,6,7,10,13,16,19}
Combination_(1,7)={3,4,7,10,13,16,19}
Combination_(1,8)={3,5,7,10,13,16,19}
Combination_(1,9)={3,6,7,10,13,16,19}
Combination_(1,10)={1,4,7,10,13,16,19}
Combination_(1,11)={1,5,8,10,13,16,19}
Combination_(1,12)={1,6,9,10,13,16,19}
```

EDITED:
 In my combination  three rows(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),...(19,20,21)... are groups. only one member will be taken and never two members. so possible solution will be not too high.

```
My_small_matrix_ having size of (7,4)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Yes, learn something about combinations and permutations: http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Comment: I suggest you change the title so that it better reflects the question's content. "User defined solutions from a matrix" is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code to get the data into a cell array where each cell houses data from each of the combinations -

```
%// Input
My_big_matrix_ = rand(21,4)

%// Use allcomb to generate all such combinations. This a MATLAB
%// file-exchange code, available at -
%// http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb
allcomb_out = allcomb(1:3,4:6,7:9,10:12,13:15,16:18,19:21);

t1 = reshape(allcomb_out',[],1);%//'
t2 = My_big_matrix_(t1,:);

out = mat2cell(t2,7*ones(1,size(allcomb_out,1)),4); %// Desired output
```

Answer (score 1):

```
C = combnk(1:21,7);   % C rows contains combinations
numcomb = size(C, 1);
combined = zeros(numcomb, 7, 3);
for k = 1:numcomb
    combined(numcomb, :, :) = reshape(My_big_matrix(numcomb(k), :), 1, 7, 3);
end
```

Comment: Ok, the edit states you don't want combinations of all lines. The combinations you have listed are ALL or are just an example of what you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

```
My_big_matrix_ = rand(21,4); %// data
n = size(My_big_matrix_,1);
g = 3; %// size of a group. Assumed to divide n

m = n/g;
combs = dec2base(0:g^m-1, g)-'0'+1;
combs = bsxfun(@plus, combs, 0:g:g*(m-1));
```

This gives

```
combs =
     1     4     7    10    13    16    19
     1     4     7    10    13    16    20
     1     4     7    10    13    16    21
     1     4     7    10    13    17    19
     1     4     7    10    13    17    20
    [...]
     3     6     9    12    15    18    20
     3     6     9    12    15    18    21
```

Then your small matrices are `My_big_matrix_(combs(1,:),:)`, `My_big_matrix_(combs(2,:),:)` etc.